# Increasing rasterio file speed rate

Tags: gdal, rasterio

I have a largish raster file (100 MB in size) with resolution of 0.05 degree. This raster file has temperature data for the entire world, but I only need data for the U.S. I have one such file for each day of the year from 2000 to 2015.

Is there a way to save time while reading this file using rasterio perhaps by specifying the extent of U.S?

Comment: GDAL has GDALRasterBand::RasterIO for that purpose http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html. Use XOff, YOff, XSize, YSize for selecting a region.

Comment: And you should use uncompressed tiff the get faster result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rasterio` lets you define [windows for read/write functions](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/topics/windowed-rw.rst). Assuming your file has dimensions of 1000 by 1000 pixels you could call rasterio to only read the upper left quarter of the image:

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open('your/data/2000/doy1.tif') as src:
     w = src.read(1, window=((0, 250), (0, 250)))
```

Where `window` is given as `((row_start, row_stop), (col_start, col_stop))` in pixel values / array notation. Windowed reads work most efficient when your data is tiled (as in `gdalinfo` reports internal tiling) and uncompressed.

Comment: Kersten is right. You can also use the `rasterio.windows.from_bounds()` function in the 1.0 pre-releases (https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/windows.py#L157) to get a window corresponding to a bounding box in the dataset's coordinate reference system.